# Dynamic text from textbox refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this:

HTML

```
<p>Text in the textbox: </p><p class="value">0</p>
<input type="text" id="textbox">
<button id="submit">Submit Value</button>
```

JQUERY

```
var tbvalue;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        tbvalue = $('#textbox').val();
        $('.value').text(tbvalue);
    });
});
```

So, that's a script that shows the text written by the user in a `<p>` tag when the user clicks a button. Now, how can I make this but without having to click the button, just when the user adds a letter or number the paragraph with the value of the textbox refresh dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.keyup()](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/)** event:

> Bind an event handler to the "keyup" JavaScript event, or trigger that
>   event on an element.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#textbox').keyup(function () {
        tbvalue = this.value;
        $('.value').text(tbvalue);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4jS54/1/)**

Comment: that's actually what i was looking for, thanks! (i'll mark it as correct answer as soon as i can)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) event.

**From Docs:**

```
Bind an event handler to the "keyup" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on
an element.
```

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#textbox').keyup(function(){
        tbvalue = $(this).val();
        $('.value').text(tbvalue);
    });
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/9Qd58/1/)**